# UML Class Diagram: Attributes and methods dependant on two classes

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram

I am trying to do a simple UML model about a car dealership.
The company has at least one store where in each they sell at least one type of a car. Each store has a name and each car has a name, type, and price. Each outlet also keeps stock of every car they sell.

I have outlined the idea in this image:

[image]

In addition to this, after every day, the number of cars sold gets recorded into a database. How would I add this to the model? Also, is there a better way to model the amount of cars in stock than to have it as a separate class? If there is a better diagram to model this type of scenario with I'd also be interested.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does an individual Car represent something with a VIN that you can drive off the lot? This model is very confusing. At least multiplicity is wrong somewhere.

Comment: Yes, a Car represents something that you can purchase from an outlet.

Comment: Where is car type?

Comment: Type is supposed to be an attribute of a Car that contains it's brand and model

Comment: How about naming your association ends?

Comment: I will do that. How about the issue of modelling a daily event (i.e. record the cars that each outlet has sold that day)?

Comment: What's the use of Stock if you simply record each individual car (and not the car type). You can't have more than one of a single actual car in stock.

Comment: As Geert said. You can just remove `Stock` and have a multiplicity of `* Car`s in `Outlet`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to model sales records. The simplest and most common is to have a sales ledger. It creates sales entries for items. The item is a separate (association) class that records the number of sold items, the price paid, the sales date, the sales person, and more. Pretty simple and straight forwards, until you get to the gory details. Ask your next dealer...

Answer (score 0):

You can model a sales record as a separate class. Let's call it DaySales. Each day, you have a new instance of DaySales, containing the date and the amount of cars sold. I have given attribute date the data type 'String', because UML does not define a Date type. But if you define it yourself, you could better use Date than String.

[image: class diagram]

I have removed the association between Car and Outlet, because it is already implicitly defined via Stock, but you can keep it as a redundant association, if you like.

I have altered the multiplicity of the association between Car and Stock, because there will be multiple cars in stock.